# Storage.put() throwing - AWSS3Provider - error uploading TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, storage, aws-amplify

- JavaScript Framework (Vue)
- Amplify APIs (Storage)
- Amplify Categories (storage)

Getting ***Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined*** while uploading media to s3 bucket using amplify storage, below is the code I am currently using

```
async onUpload(fileArr) {
  if (fileArr.length > 0) {
    console.log("fileArr", fileArr);
    fileArr.map(async (obj) => {
      try {
        console.log({ Storage, Amplify });
        console.log("Object =>", obj);
        let baseData = await this.toBase64(obj);
        console.log("Base Data =>", baseData);
        const arrayBuffer = decode(baseData);
        console.log("Array buffer =>", arrayBuffer);
        let result = await Storage.put(
          `hub/${obj.name}`,
          arrayBuffer,
          {
            contentType: obj.type,
          }
        );
        console.log("S3 Upload Result =>", result);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error in uploading", err);
      }
    });
  }
},
```

I tried to convert media to base64 before uploading but still getting same error

***ERROR OUTPUT***

```
Error - AWSS3Provider - error uploading TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
```

I granted full access to my IAM user and role but it didn't work either, I looked for multiple solution available online but still I didn't make it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also faced this problem while uploading data to s3 using Apmplify.

The problem is not in your code its library version issue, make sure to use same Amplify version which is used on server

Latest Amplify version is 4.3.0
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-amplify